# How to prevent getting focus on an input when i hide it (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code which adds a li with a value from an input field. There is a fadeToggle function on that input. I want to focus it when it appears and don't show it when it hides. With the current code it gets focus before it's being hidden.

```js
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
   $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle(250).focus();
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            var todoText = $(this).val();
            $(this).val('');
            $('ul').prepend('<li>' + todoText + '</li>');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <button>add</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li>carrot</li>
    <li>onion</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What, exactly is the problem? Please clarify.

Comment: Unclear! can you elaborate a little more your current problem?

Comment: [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) takes a callback function that can be used to run code after the fade happens. e.g. `$(..).fadeToggle(250, function () { $(this).focus();});`

Comment: try to add some item to the list and click anywhere to get unfocused the input field, then try to hide it with "add" button and before be hidden it gets focused again, i don't want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the fadeToggle() event to complete before you set the focus.

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
   $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle( 250 ,function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5yq4ajn/9/

Answer (score 1):

You `focus()` event is getting executed before completion of `fadeToggle()`. Just pass it as a callback and it will work fine

```js
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    $('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle( 250 ,function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            var todoText = $(this).val();
            $(this).val('');
            $('ul').prepend('<li>' + todoText + '</li>');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <button>add</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li>carrot</li>
    <li>onion</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a `document.ready()` event handler, you can give the `input` the initial focus. Then, if you supply the optional completion function argument to **[`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)**, it will run after the effect has completed, at which time you can determine if focus should be applied or not (doesn't make sense to focus it if it's not visible).

```js
$(function(){
  let input = $('input[type="text"]');
  input.focus(); // Give input initial focus
 
  $('button').on('click', function (event) {
    input.fadeToggle(250, function(){
      // If the input is visible, give it the focus, if not don't
      input.css("opacity") !== 0 ? input.focus() : input.blur();
    });
    
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            var todoText = $(this).val();
            $(this).val('');
            $('ul').prepend('<li>' + todoText + '</li>');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <button>add</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li>carrot</li>
    <li>onion</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback to the function `fadeToggle`:

```
$('input[type="text"]').fadeToggle(250, function() {
   this.focus();
});
```

**Recommendation:** store the live jQuery object to avoid repeated look up of `'input[type="text"]'`

```
var $input = $('input[type="text"]');
```

```js
var $input = $('input[type="text"]');
$('button').on('click', function(event) {  
  $input.fadeToggle(250, function() {
    this.focus();
  });
});

$input.on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      var todoText = $(this).val();
      $(this).val('');
      $('ul').prepend('<li>' + todoText + '</li>');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
  <button>add</button>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li>carrot</li>
    <li>onion</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### `fadeToggle`

> `complete` (callback)
>
> **Type:** Function()
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.